# Adding hstore entries to an uninitialized (NULL) column

Tags: postgresql, update, null, hstore

I got bitten by this "feature" recently.

If your `hstore` column is uninitialized and you start adding entries to it, they are all silently swallowed without error.

Is this expected?

```
 create table test_hstore(id int, map hstore);
 insert into test_hstore(id,map) values(0, '');
 INSERT 0 1

 select * from test_hstore ;
  id | map 
 ----+-----
   0 | 


 update test_hstore set map = map || hstore('key1', 'value1') where id = 0;
 UPDATE 1

 select * from test_hstore;
  id |       map        
 ----+------------------
   0 | "key1"=>"value1"


 update test_hstore set map = null where id = 0;
 UPDATE 1

 select * from test_hstore;
  id |  map   
 ----+--------
   0 | (null)


 update test_hstore set map = map || hstore('key1', 'value1') where id = 0;
 UPDATE 1

 select * from test_hstore;
  id |  map   
 ----+--------
   0 | (null)
```

If I cannot have a not null constraint on the column, can I safeguard myself by doing something like that(this doesn't actually work):

```
UPDATE test_hstore SET map = (IF map IS NULL
                                THEN  '' || hstore('key1', 'value1')
                                ELSE map || hstore('key1', 'value1'))
WHERE id = 0;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SQL, `NULL (operator) (value)` is generally `NULL`.

This is not unique to hstore, and is the norm for everything.

The empty string `''` is different to NULL. `'' || 'somestring'` is `'somestring'`, wheras `NULL || 'somestring'` is `NULL`.

The same is true for `hstore`. Just like `NULL + 1` is `NULL`.

If this is a problem for you, you should probably store empty `hstore` values instead of `NULL` and assign a `NOT NULL` constraint on the column.

Answer (score 6):

[@Craig provides a detailed **explanation**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84858/3684) and the best advice to ***avoid*** the problem: define the column `NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` - which adds 1 byte per row to storage (typically) where the columns could be `NULL` instead.

The simple, standard ***solution*** for the problem at hand is [**`COALESCE()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) - like with any other data type that can be `NULL`. It's a completely reasonable design to allow `NULL` values in the column, you just have to handle it properly.

<sub>Your idea with <strike>`IF`</strike> was close but that's not part of the SQL language (neither in standard SQL nor in Postgres). Some other RDBMS like MySQL introduce `IF` and `IFNULL` to SQL, but those add *nothing* over the standard features [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) and [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).</sub>

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test_hstore AS
SELECT '1'::int AS id, NULL::hstore AS map;  -- test table with 1 row

UPDATE test_hstore SET map = map || hstore('key1', 'value1')
RETURNING *;

id  |  map   
----+--------
1   | (null)

UPDATE test_hstore SET map = COALESCE(map, '') || hstore('key1', 'value1')
RETURNING *;

id  |   map        
----+------------------
1   | "key1"=>"value1"
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6652d46478c5bd8b6f9c5e2def2e9e5c)*
Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2842e/1)